# В IntellijIDEA отсутствует раздел Version Control. Как исправить?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Установил на `вин-10` `IntellijIDEA Community 2019.1.3`.
Студию ставлю на диск D. *Раньше на `вин-8` стояла студия на диске D - проблем не наблюдал.*
Скачал и установил `Git`, тоже на диск D.
Прописал `PATH`.

Но не могу подключить `Git` так как в настройках идеи вообще нет раздела `Version Control`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При старте идеи импорт не могу выбрать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал переустановить идею - не помогло.

Что это может быть? Может что-то упустил, так как идею давно не ставил. Может баг самой идеи?

---

Дополнение: в меню `File -> New`  нет пункта типа: `import project from version control`.

А в `VLS` очень мало пунктов. На принтскире видно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Искать нужно в **Settings - Plugins**.  Найдите в marcetplace и инсталлируйте плагины **Git Integration** и **Github**. Или если они уже инсталлированы - то активируйте.

Comment: Оказалось все просто - эти плагины были неактивны хоть и установлены. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Version control появится при запущенном проекте и настроенным git.
Скачайте Ваш проект из репозитория (git clone), откройте его, и у Вас появится пункт GIT в VCS

Comment: Проект создан. Настройка git - что имеете ввиду?  Так же вопрос по поводу остального попрошу подробнее ибо как по мне, то я как раз все что мог - то и сделал. Вроде ничего не упустил.

Comment: Вроде бы начинаю понимать всю эту многоступенчатую схему, буду пробовать дальше.